# query not working for foreign key as a composite primary key of another table oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I am trying to add two foreign keys for an associative entity in SQL Oracle. The primary key that I am referring from another table is a composite primary key. When I try to enter the SQL it says

> no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

The code that I used to create the tbl_customer

```
 CREATE TABLE tbl_Customer(
customer_id     NUMBER(4)
    CONSTRAINT pk_customer PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerName    VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
Telephone       VARCHAR2(10),
CusEmail        VARCHAR2(20),
    CONSTRAINT cus_email UNIQUE(CusEmail),

location_id     NUMBER(4)
    CONSTRAINT fk_location_id references tbl_Location(location_id));
```

SQL to create tbl_Vehicle

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Vehicle(
   vehicle_id   NUMBER(4),
   PlateNo      VARCHAR2(10),
    CONSTRAINT pk_v PRIMARY KEY(vehicle_id,PlateNo),
   Brand        VARCHAR2(20),
   Model        VARCHAR2(10),
   TotalNoSeats     NUMBER(2),
   Class        VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT no_seats CHECK (TotalNoSeats<100),
     driver_id      NUMBER(4)
        CONSTRAINT fk_driveridV references tbl_Driver(driver_id),
     location_id    NUMBER(4)
        CONSTRAINT fk_locationV references tbl_Location(location_id));
```

The associative table is

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Customer_Vehicle(
customer_id NUMBER(4)
CONSTRAINT fk_customer_id references tbl_Customer(customer_id),
vehicle_id NUMBER(4)
CONSTRAINT fk_vehicle_id references tbl_Vehicle(vehicle_id)
);
```

where the error is in this line

```
 CONSTRAINT fk_vehicle_id references tbl_Vehicle(vehicle_id)
                                             *
```

Is this error because vehicle_id is a composite primary key?
Please help!!

Comment: Then how to create the foreign key for the associative table?

Comment: You need `PlateNo` column as well in child table

Comment: Could you please show me how to query it properly for the child table

Comment: You need to add `PlateNo` column in `tbl_Customer_Vehicle` table first

Comment: Do you mean the query has to be like this CREATE TABLE tbl_Customer_Vehicle(
    customer_id NUMBER(4)
    CONSTRAINT fk_customer_id references tbl_Customer(customer_id),
    vehicle_id NUMBER(4)
    CONSTRAINT fk_vehicle_id references tbl_Vehicle(vehicle_id),
    PlateNumber NUMBER(10)
    CONSTRAINT fk_Platen0 references tbl_Vehicle(PlateNumber 
    );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99443/discussion-between-andrew-and-vr46).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `PlateNo` column in `tbl_Customer_Vehicle` table and define foreign key on it.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Customer_Vehicle
(
customer_id NUMBER(4)
CONSTRAINT fk_customer_id references tbl_Customer(customer_id),
vehicle_id NUMBER(4),
PlateNo      VARCHAR2(10),
CONSTRAINT fk_vehicle_id_PlateNo FOREIGN KEY(vehicle_id,PlateNo)
            references tbl_Vehicle(vehicle_id,PlateNo)
);
```

Comment: still it shows this error message     CONSTRAINT fk_vehicle_id references tbl_Vehicle(vehicle_id),
                                                    *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Comment: Did you try my code, I have defined it like this CONSTRAINT `fk_vehicle_id_PlateNo references tbl_Vehicle(vehicle_id,PlateNo)`. You error message shows `fk_vehicle_id references tbl_Vehicle(vehicle_id)`. Please use my query

Comment: Yes, I used it shows this error message CONSTRAINT fk_vehicle_id_PlateNo references tbl_Vehicle(vehicle_id,PlateNo)
                                                       *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: yes, it worked. Thank you soooo much. I was trying to fix this from yesterday. Thanks again :)